# Open ajax modal only if href contains value

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I load a ajax modal every 30 min but on my page i have more ajax modals that can be clicked by the user
this is my code:

```
<a href="modal.html" data-toggle="ajaxModal"></a>
<script>
    setInterval(function () {
        if($('#ajaxModal').attr('aria-hidden') == 'false') return;

        $('*[data-toggle="ajaxModal"]').click();
    }
    ,300000);
</script>
```

Is it possible to open only the modal with modal.html as href? Instead of all ajax modals on the page

Comment: you can add an id to that specific modal and only open it.

Comment: @DanielX2010 I tried that but i keeps opening all modals

Comment: There is not enough information provided to recreate your issue

Answer (score 0):

as for bootstrap it should be something like this:

```
$('*[data-toggle="ajaxModal"][data-target="modal.html"]').click();
```

can you please send an html element of such a modal so i can make this example more accurate?

Answer (score 0):

I Added a id and its working now.

```
<a href="modal.html" id="modal" data-toggle="ajaxModal"></a>
<script>
setInterval(function () {
        if($('#ajaxModal').attr('aria-hidden') == 'false') return;

        $('[id="modal"]*[data-toggle="ajaxModal"]').click();
    }
    ,300000);
</script>
```